# How does BigQuery query / analysis pricing work?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a [BigQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) table with about 34M rows (it will grow to ~500M in a few months).  I get the storage pricing, but I don't really understand how the query / analysis pricing works.

For example, if I run a query that is a simple select that returns 3 columns from about 20 records, it says that 644 MB was processed. Even if I remove columns or criteria on the `where` clause, it still shows that I'm processing 6xx MB of data.

Interestingly, if I run a select count(*) from table, it reports 0 bytes processed.

One of the use cases for BigQuery is to create dashboards and ad hoc reports. However, I don't see how this can be practical if it's going to cost $.03 for every two queries made against the table.

Am I missing something? Is there a strategy for reducing the amount of data processed for simple data access?

Comment: great question. when i decide to have 10k reputation, ill get this re-opened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the BigQuery pricing documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/pricing#table). Basically, you pay for the full size of the columns you access, since every BigQuery query reads every column mentioned. For example,

```
select foo, bar from table1 where foo=1
```

will charge you for access to the entire size of the foo and bar columns in table1.

COUNT(*) reads table metadata to get the count, so it doesn't cost anything.

One way to reduce the cost is to split your data into multiple tables. You can combine tables in a single query by indicating comma-separated tables (as in `select foo from table1,table2`). You can also cache results (BigQuery doesn't do any caching on its own).

Comment: BigQuery does cache by default now, which is very useful on the pricing side of things.